# React - How to get cookies which is set from the grafana?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, cookies, grafana

I have one react app and grafana proxy app which has backend code(apis) as well.

I am login to grafana through my react app like,

```
<Iframe
     title="Login"
     src={`${grafanaBaseUrl}/login?token=${authToken}`}
     width="0"
     height="0"
/>
```

Once this rendered successfully, there will 2 urls cookies in the browser. One is my frontend app url and another one is backend url which has grafana proxy code.

So cookies will get create like,

Frontend url: "Some cookies"

Backend url: "grafana_session_expiry" and "grafana_session"

Now though my react app I can get cookies like `document.cookie` which returns only frontend app's cookies.

How can I get backend app's cookie through react?
Here, I want to know whether user is logged into grafana or not by getting this cookies `grafana_session_expiry` or `grafana_session`.

Comment: It looks like insecure setup. You can allow unauthenticated access to Grafana and you will have the same security level.